# Netbeans 8.2, "make controller" button disappeared

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder, netbeans-8

I dont understand what is wrong.. Netbeans just ignoring .fxml file and I cant make controller or open it in SceneBuilder. JavaFX works normally.

[Expectation (other project groups)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mivqT.png)

[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmQXU.png)

Netbeans works normally in other project groups.
It this project is same setup like in others.

Can somebody tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found solution. If you copy .fxml from "reality" img project.. Netbeans start recognizing .fxml files... somehow. Ill leave this here for others.